# What's the fastest way to convert pixel based css into percentage based one?

Tags: css, pixel, percentage

I need to convert a website from pixels into percentages. The goal is to fit the page in every device. I would go converting div by div.
But is this the best way? If I chose this route, anyway, my font isn't scaling at all.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after testing and lookin around, I've decided to put this code in the markup and now the site fits every screen.

Basically, it says: render the screen as if you were viewing it in a screen 1300px, wide.